# How to resolve C++ member function vs C function with the same name?

Tags: c, sockets

I got a server class in server.h:

```
namespace tcp{

     #include <sys/types.h>       
     #include <sys/socket.h>
     #include <netinet/in.h>
     #include <arpa/inet.h>
     #include <netdb.h>

     class Server{
     private:
           int listener; //socket fd 
     public:
     /* ...... */
           void run();
           int listen();
     /* ...... */
     }
}
```

In server.cpp:

```
usinge namespace tcp;

void Server::run(){
     /* ...do something to get socket for listening...*/
     listen();
     /* ...do something else...*/
}

int Server::listen(){
        if (listen(listener, 10) == -1){
                 perror("listen");
                 exit(3)
        }
}
```

The compiler can't distinguish between Server::listen() call and the listen() system call. My solution is to wrap the `#include` directives inside the namespace std. However, I'm not sure if it will conflict if other files include those system headers, or some other problems. Any suggestion other than name changing?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `::listen()` should work for you

Comment: Shouldn't it better be `namespace tcp { ... [Server::run(), Server::listen()] ... }` in the cpp file instead of `using namespace tcp;`  - since you're not actually using the namespace, but defining stuff that's in it?

Comment: Do not include other files in your own header file, unless absolutely necessary. Those includes should be in the source, not header file. Also, do not include headers inside a namespace, because then all typedefs, structures and functions will be in that namespace too, but not pre-processor macros (which those files have quite a lot of, even if it's mostly normal "constants".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefix the C version with `::`

i.e.

```
if (::listen(listener, 10) == -1) {
   ...
}
```

i.e. using the global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You want `::listen(listener,10)`

This will tell the compiler to look at the global scope.

Answer (score 3):

First you should move all #includes out of the namespace tcp. To distinguish between the class listen and the C listen you just call `Server::listen` (or listen inside a class member function) and `::listen` (or just listen outside a class member function) for the C `listen` function.

Answer (score 2):

You should not mess with the `std` namespace. Just write `::listen` to refer to the symbol in the global namespace.